# Replace Google maps map?

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps

Is it possible to replace the map that the google maps web applet uses? I mean like replacing a certain URL that the applet retrieves the maps from. Also, what format are they in? Are they all just images (one for each zoom level) or are they dynamically generated?

Comment: Everything you need to not hard-code the maps: http://goo.gl/wRzA3

Comment: Google maps is not based on a Java applet.  Tag removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can replace the whole map. Google maps consists of just images (jpg and png), they are all 256x256 pixel in size (called "tiles").

On zoom level 0 (the lowest zoom level, in which the entire world can be seen on one map) there is only one tile containing the whole map. On the next zoom level this tile gets divided into 4 subsections, which form the next zoom level. Therefore on zoom level 1 you have 4 tiles and so on..

In general the number of tiles per zoom level is as follows:

`number_of_tiles_per_zoom_level`=`4`^`zoom_level`;

That means on zoom level 21 there are 4398046511104 tiles :O

To replace the map with your own you would have to generate those tiles from your map first and then you can use them inside google maps.

Have a look at: [ImageMapTypes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=de#ImageMapTypes)

And here is an example using this technique: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image

Comment: I'm guessing I'd have to write a script to split up a larger image. If my calculations are correct, the original image has to be 17179869 184x17179869184 pixels!

Comment: Either you write your own, or maybe use some existing program like http://www.maptiler.org/ for example, there are a lots of programs out there. On zoom level 21 the original would be sqrt(4398046511104) * 256 = 536 870 912 (536870912 x 536870912 pixels), but your map doesn't have to have 21 zoom levels, basically the size of your original determines how much zoom levels there are.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. But you need to do it the right way: Theres the Google Maps API, custom overlays: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#GroundOverlays

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to physically replace the whole map? Instead of overlaying it?

Comment: I think so. I've seen engines running the GMaps API without showing the original map. Take your time and read the docs. You can show the custom layer and use only the navigation+zoom (as I understand that's what you're looking for)